# What is the proper way to delete array of char pointers in c++

Tags: c++

In C++ I have the follow class:

```
class Command
{
    char *_str;
    char *attr[100];
    bool _used[100];
    size_t wordsCount = 0;

    void _clearCommand()
    {
        delete[] _str;
        for(int i = 0; i <= wordsCount; i ++)
            delete[] attr[i];
    }
private:
    Command(const char *str = "") {...}

    ~Command()
    {
        _clearCommand();
    }

    Command(Command &other)
    {
        setStr(other.getStr());
    }

    Command &operator= (const char *str)
    {
        setStr(str);
        return *this;
    }

    Command &operator= (Command &other)
    {
        setStr(other.getStr());
        return *this;
    }

    void setStr(const char *str)
    {
        _clearCommand();
        _str = new char[strlen(str)];
        strcpy(_str, str);
        _str[strlen(str)] = '\0';
        splitCommand();
    }

    void splitCommand(){ 

    }

}
```

This function splitCommand splits the _str on spaces and each i-th word is saved in attr[i]. For example: 
`"command word1     word2"` will be splitted like this `attr[0] = "command", attr[1] = "word1", attr[2] = "word2"`
Empty words are omitted. 
But from time to time I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Am I deleting the dynamic content right?

P.S. Sorry I've forgotten to say that I cant use stl containers and class string.

Comment: Everything would be much simpler if you used `std::string` and `std::vector`, but basically, you can only `delete[]` what you've allocated with `new[]`. If you can't guarantee that that's how the strings you're getting were created, you'll have to copy them.

Comment: FWIW, unless you have some requirement that stops you from using the standard library, you should be using a `std:vector<str::string>` for all of you arrays.

Comment: Proper way to fix it in C++ is not to use `new` `delete` or C style array. Just switch your code to use `std::vector` and `std::string`. This way memory management is done for free by library.

Comment: `_str = new char[strlen(str)];` should be `_str = new char[strlen(str) + 1];` to allocate sufficient space for the terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to properly associate `new[]` with `delete[]` but
you need to allocate `strlen()+1` characters before `strcpy()`
because the ending `'\0'` will overflow.
Then the following memory is probably corrupted which could
lead to bad de-allocation.

---

And also, your loop tries to delete one time too many

```
        for(int i = 0; i <= wordsCount; i ++) // < instead of <= ?
            delete[] attr[i];
```

If you are lucky, this last pointer is null and `delete[]`
does nothing, if not you try to delete a random address.

---

(and I agree with all the comments that recommend the usage
of `std::string` and `std::vector` ;^)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look how much simpler it is when you do use C++ features:

```cpp
class Command
{
    std::string m_str;
    std::vector<std::string> m_attr;
    std::vector<bool>  m_used;

    void _clearCommand()
    {
        m_attr.clear();
    }

private:
    Command(const std::string& s = {}) {...}

    Command &operator=(const std::string& str)
    {
        setStr(str);
        return *this;
    }

// note rule of zero will cause automatic creation of:
// copy/move constructors copy/move assignment

    void setStr(const std::string& str)
    {
        _clearCommand();
        m_str = str;
        splitCommand();
    }

    std::string getStr() const
    {
        return m_str;
    }

    void splitCommand(){ 

    }
}
```

Comment: I would even remove the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: me to, but he does some strange thing there, so I didn't remove it.

Comment: I would remove it anyway.  It is buggy and to me, it looks like the OP tried to do a deep copy, when containers will do it correctly and precisely.

Comment: You may want to be explicit that "the proper way to delete array of char pointers" is to not need to

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper way to delete array of char pointers in c++

If you allocate an array dynamically with `new[]`, then you delete the array with `delete[]`.

For example, if you created like this:

```
_str = new char[strlen(str)];
```

Then you delete like this:

```
delete[] _str;
```

---

> ```
> delete[] attr[i];
> ```

You never wrote `attr[i] = new ...[]`, so you may not delete it. You may `delete[]` only a pointer from `new[]`.

---

> ```
> _str = new char[strlen(str)];
> strcpy(_str, str);
> _str[strlen(str)] = '\0';
> ```

The behaviour is undefined because the array is too small for the string. `_str[strlen(str)]` is outside the bounds of the array. You forgot to allocate space for the null terminator.